# spark unit test framework examples OTHER THAN com.holdenkarau

Tags: unit-testing, apache-spark, scalatest

I am trying to write test case of spark scala application code. So I am planning to use `SharedSparkSession` for this purpose.

I've seen other framework such as **com.holdenkarau** but I am looking for any other alternative especially using `SharedSparkSeesion`.

So I tried finding sample examples using this `SharedSparkSession` from the web, but I am unable to do so.

If you have any example, please post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spark own test framework can be used in Scala, SparkSession present there. Some dependencies have to be included, for Maven below, can be converted to Sbt.
ScalaTest example: https://apache.googlesource.com/spark/+/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/ColumnExpressionSuite.scala

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.suffix}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.suffix}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-catalyst_${scala.suffix}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i will try this over the weekend or the next week. thanks.!

Comment: I am using exactly the same in my code, hence accepted the answer, thanks a lot, it saved my time to write my own, : )

Comment: Thanks, the `spark-catalyst` dependency wasn't obvious and I was looking all over for that.