# implement unit tests in a spark + hdfs + mongo environment

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop

I just joined a 2 years old project that reads data from a HDFS, do some processing with spark, and writes results to mongo database.
My concern is that there is no tests.

What is the best approach to keep it simple for the first test ? 
Mock HDFS + Mongo ? if its possible ? 
Embed HDFS + Mongo ? if its possible ?

Comment: There is an Embedded HDFS for Integration tests, yes... I'm not sure about Mongo, but I would think there are. Otherwise, there's always Docker

Comment: for Spark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326244/spark-unit-test-framework-examples-other-than-com-holdenkarau/52327440#52327440

Comment: for mongo : https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo